# Retrieve multiple rows from SQL Server in a web service and xamarin android?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, web-services, xamarin.android

I want to retrieve multiple rows from SQL Server in a web service. I get 2 rows as result when I search jo number 1 and my table name is `TestOrderStatus`.

While I get only one row in the search result.

Thanks for all

```
public class ReturnOrder
{
    public string Message;
    public int QtqSlit;
    public int QtyPcs;
    public string Design;
}

[WebMethod(MessageName = "OrderStatus", Description = "OrderStatus new Order")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlInclude(typeof(ReturnOrder))]
public ReturnOrder OrderStatus(string JO)  /// get list of notes
{
    int QtqSlit = 0;
    int QtyPcs = 0;
    String Design = "";
    string Message = "";

    SqlDataReader reader;
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(DBConnection.ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT QtqSlit,QtyPcs,Design  FROM TestOrderStatus where JO=@JO");
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JO", JO);

        connection.Open();

        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                QtqSlit = reader.GetInt32(0);
                QtyPcs = reader.GetInt32(1);
                Design = reader.GetString(2);
            }
        }

        if (QtqSlit == 0)
        {
            Message = " user name or password is incorrect";
        }

        reader.Close();
        connection.Close();
    }

    ReturnOrder rt = new ReturnOrder();
    rt.Message = Message;
    rt.QtqSlit = QtqSlit;
    rt.QtyPcs = QtyPcs;
    rt.Design = Design;

    return rt;
}
```

Comment: The rest of the code
public class ReturnOrder
{
    public string Message;
    public int QtqSlit;
    public int QtyPcs;
    public string Design;


}

Comment: First you don't need the internal for loop. This will read the three fields of the current record for three times. One is enough. Second the while loop, after the first loop (first record), runs again a second time replacing the values loaded in the first loop (and if there are 3 record it runs again and so on). So you end with just one record, the last one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to much now web service is ok , But when he summoned the values in  Xamrian Android doesn't know.

public class Mainlistview : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

```
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Mainlistview);


        ListView ListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);



        Selling.WebServiceDB ws = new Selling.WebServiceDB();
        ws.OrderStatusListCompleted += Ws_OrderStatusListCompleted;
        ws.OrderStatusListAsync(Convert.ToString(1));



    }


    private void Ws_OrderStatusListCompleted(object sender, Selling.OrderStatusListCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        ListView ListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);
        string msg = "";

         if (e.Result.QtqSlit.ToString().Equals("0"))
        {
            msg = e.Result.Message;
        }
        else
        {

            // full class
            List<TableItem> tableItems = new List<TableItem>();
            tableItems.Add(new TableItem("" + e.Result.QtqSlit, "" + e.Result.QtyPcs, Resource.Drawable.Icon));
            ListView.Adapter = new HomeScreenAdapter(this, tableItems);


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a List for multiple rows if you want more than one result. So your code may be like this.

```
public class ReturnOrder
{
    public string Message;
    public int QtqSlit;
    public int QtyPcs;
    public string Design;


}


[WebMethod(MessageName = "OrderStatus", Description = "OrderStatus new Order")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlInclude(typeof(List<ReturnOrder>))]
public List<ReturnOrder> OrderStatus(string JO)  /// get list of notes
{
    List<ReturnOrder> result=new List<ReturnOrder>();
    int QtqSlit = 0;
    int QtyPcs = 0;
    String Design = "";
    string Message = "";

    //try
    //{
        SqlDataReader reader;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(DBConnection.ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT QtqSlit,QtyPcs,Design  FROM TestOrderStatus where JO=@JO");
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JO", JO);
            connection.Open();

            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                    QtqSlit = reader.GetInt32(0);
                    QtyPcs = reader.GetInt32(1);
                    Design = reader.GetString(2);

    ReturnOrder rt = new ReturnOrder();
    rt.Message = Message;
    rt.QtqSlit = QtqSlit;
    rt.QtyPcs = QtyPcs;
    rt.Design = Design;

result.add(rt);


            }
            if (QtqSlit == 0)
            {
                Message = " user name or password is in correct";
            }
            reader.Close();

            connection.Close();
        }

    //}
    //catch (Exception ex)
    //{
    //    Message = " cannot access to the data";
    //}




    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you to much now web service is ok , But when he summoned the values in  Xamrian Android doesn't know.

Comment: Sorry for late answer, but did you change returned data type List<ReturnOrder> in the Xamarian ?